# Yii2 Where to catch an exception thrown from a bootstrapper module?

Tags: yii, yii2

In my config, I have a custom class bootstrapping to fetch data

```
'bootstrap' => [
    [
        'class' => 'app\components\DataProvider',
        'campaignJsonUrl' => 'https://example.com/api.json',
    ],
],
```

And I would like to catch exceptions throwns for an unreachable url or invalid json for example. But I can't figure out where to catch these.

I made a custom error handler:

```
'errorHandler' => [
    // use 'site/error' action to display errors
    'class' => 'app\components\ErrorHandler',         
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
```

In which the error seems to reach `ErrorHandler.renderException()` method if I override it, however it never reaches the `SiteController.actionError()` method, I guess because it happens before any controller action. How can I make the ErrorHandler run `SiteController.actionError()` so it will show the website's error page with the correct layout?

**NOTE:** My overridden renderException() method only sends the exception to a Slack API then returns `parent::renderException($exception)`